# Fantasy movie where underground creatures get angry at something people are doing and dig their way to the surface

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've been trying to find this fantasy movie but I remember almost nothing. The only thing I know for sure is that there is a scene where some creatures who lived underground were coming out of it and they were not really happy.

I have this very clear image in my mind of these weird looking creatures that I believe were some kind of fairies - not like the little cute ones like *Tinker Bell*, they looked more like trolls or a slender *Groot*, maybe they were also bigger than common fairies (I also think there were these classic pretty fairies in the movie too), and I don't remember if they were made of wood, stone or something like that, but they had kind of earthy colors - and at some point, near the end, because of something that triggers them, they come out of the ground to the surface. I don't remember exactly if they did so breaking or digging through the ground or going through tunnels. I also don't remember if they had wings or were able to fly, but they were bipedal.

I'll try to explain more thing of the plot, but anything that I'll say right now are things I can't remember for sure if it's really from this movie or if it's a false memory, but I do think it's from the same thing.

I don't remember if the main character is a little girl or boy, but it is definitely a child. I believe they moved to this house with they family (probably mom and dad, but I remember more of the dad) and I know it's something about their dad's work. Maybe their dad does some research (maybe about these creatures) and either they moved to this house because of this job or his research is the reason why those creatures come out of the ground later - or both.
This child kinda connects with nature, they become friends with the fairies or something like that, but I don't know if it's the regular ones or these weird looking ones, but somehow they find about this magical part of the world, the creatures and stuff.

Then there is a huge blank in my mind about the plot until the end when the underground creatures get angry about this thing that triggers them (that I believe has something to do with the dad's work or research) and they start to dig (?) their way out of the ground to go to the surface to do something. The view of this particular scene of the creatures is like those ant tunnels images that you can see the ground and everything else from the side, like there is a glass.
I don't remember the resolution of the movie, but it ends well. The creatures go back to the ground, probably the kid convinced their dad to help or stop what he was doing before and everything ends happily.

I don't remember what year or decade it's from, but if I were to say, it's probably from the 90's. It is probably at least 15 years old, because I watched it when I was a kid. It was dubbed in Portuguese, since I'm from Brazil and it was on TV, but I believe it's an English language movie.

There's almost no chance of it being a horror movie, as I've always been scared of those, I'm almost certain it's just a children's fantasy one.

It has some similar vibes to *The Spiderwick Chronicles (2008)*, but I don't think it is it.

While searching for this movie, I heard about *Photographing Fairies* (1997) and *FairyTale: A True Story* (1997) and looked at some screenshots of both, it wasn't enough to light any memory nor did I see anything underground related, but I also don't remember watching it before, so there is a small chance it can be one of these, but I don't think so.

Comment: YOur description sounds somewhat like the movie The Fairy King of Ar, aka Beings. It was made in 1998 and is about a kid that tries to save a group of fairies trapped underground in a mine. There is a scene where the fairies rush towards the surface, but they are not digging or angry. The townspeople are scared of them though and think they are demons.

Comment: Similar to [PAN'S LABYRINTH](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVZRnnVSQ8k)?

Comment: I agree that it definitely sounds like The Fairy King of Ar. I couldn't originally remember the name but I found the 2002 disc that I had, the evil fairy-like thing could be the red creature on the front cover of the DVD case.

Comment: Your description so reminds me of [Artemis Fowl](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3089630/) but its from 2020 so that doesn't match with you having seen it as a kid.